# Cannot set div width in CSS

Tags: css, layout

I would like to make three inner divs have the same size.
Can you tell me what's wrong with this?

http://jsfiddle.net/8uasY/

actually, I would like the inner divs to be evenly spaced , so when I add a margin I get this : http://jsfiddle.net/8uasY/11/ , the inner divs are not on the same line any more

Comment: You've got a bunch of suggestions to choose from. The crucial issue is why you have double wrapped your content. If you don't need the second wrapping layer, just remove it like @KyleSevenoaks suggests. Otherwise you can use any of the other CSS styling options.

Comment: The third one is jumping onto the second line because 3x33% plus your margin is greater that 100%.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/4kzhk/

by removing the *float* from the *.inner* div and by **not** specifying width, the the width is dynamic it lets you use padding and margin freely.

one more important thing: 
notice i change the selector from:

```
.pricing div {
 ...
}
```

to:

```
.pricing > div {
 ...
}
```

the > symbol says select **only** **direct children** which are divs of *'.pricing'*

Comment: Thanks for the `>` hint. I had to effect a work-around the other day because I didn't know that :)

Comment: That said, I'm still not convinced that the double wrapping is necessary :)

Comment: mLar, your welcome.

@Nick, there's a lot more from that came from:
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize/?search_index=7

Answer (score 2):

check this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/8uasY/1/) you were not using selectors correctly. which was making your six `div's` of same width instead of only three child `div's`.

**use**

```
.pricing div div{
float :left ;
width:33% ;

}
```

**instead of**

```
.pricing div{
float :left ;
width:33% ;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need all the wrapping divs, just select the div.inner

```
.inner 
{
    border : 1px solid #ccc ;
    border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;
    min-height :120px ;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    padding :20px ;
    box-sizing: border-box; 
    float: left ;
    width: 33%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/8uasY/12/

Comment: Uhh, actually that's a mistake on my part. Use the `width: 33%;`

Answer (score 0):

The width 33% is being applied to all divs under you main div. you need to give you container divs a class, change your HTML/CSS like so ...

```
<div class="pricing">   
   <div class="outer"><div   class="inner">  satarter   </div> </div>
   <div class="outer"><div  class="inner">   best value </div> </div>
   <div class="outer"><div  class="inner">   busness    </div> </div>
</div>
<style>
.pricing div.outer {
    float :left ;
    Width:33% ;

}

.inner 
{
    border : 1px solid #ccc ;
    Background-color: yellow;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;
    border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;
    min-height :120px ;
     box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
     /*margin :10px ;*/
     padding :20px ;
      -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box; 
   /*width:180px ;*/
Width: 100%;
   display :block ;
   float: left ;
}

</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You weren't correctly selecting the divs.

You can either:

```
.pricing {width: 100%}
.pricing div {
float: left;
width: 33%
}
```

And remove one wrapper div:

```
<div class="pricing">   
   <div class="inner">  satarter   </div>
   <div class="inner">   best value </div>
   <div class="inner">   busness    </div>
</div>
```

Or just select the actual divs to increase in size:

```
.pricing {width: 100%}
.pricing div div {
float: left;
width: 33%
}
```